# Setting up PayPal Express checkout in virtocommerce - "URL of store not set"

Tags: virtocommerce

I'm setting up Virto Commerce hosted in Azure. 
version - 2.13.35
I have my store all setup and now I'm trying to setup the PayPal Express checkout module (version 2.12.1).
I've not been able to find any documentation about how to configure the module.  Looking in the VC platform under "Paypal Express checkout - gateway settings" the settings I see are:

- api password
- api signature
- api username

On the PayPal side, I don't see anything that directly coorelates to these settings. On the paypal side I created a Sandbox account email+ppmerchang@gmail.com.  Then in Apps & Credentials I went to "Express Checkout via Braintree SDK Credentials" which game me the following

- Sandbox Account
- AccessToken
- ExpiryDate

I mapped the merchant the fields as follows:

- api username -> email+ppmerchant@gmail.com
- api password -> merchant
- account password api signature -> AccessToken

When I tried that and tested I got the following exception back:
POST storefrontapi/cart/createorder 500 internal server error
"URL of store not set"

Obviously I'm missing something, going to the wrong place, using inccorect values or whatever.  Can somebody please point me in the right direction?  This seems like it should be a lot easier.

Comment: UPDATE - clicking on Account details provides: username, password and signature under API Credentials.  However, I still get URL of store not set.

Answer (score 2):

try setting store url in virto commerce admin, as paypal express does need to know where to redirect user after checkout is complete.

[image]

Comment: yeah - that fixed that problem.  Thank you.  Sadly - we're on to the next problem.

Comment: @Jake it gets easier ;) post the problem and someone will try to help